# Total Voc and Vmp with charge controller

Tags: solar-cell

I currently have Blue Sky 2512i charge controller. Great unit! We have three 75W panels in parallel. Blue Sky limits the Voc and Vmp to 28V and 16.5V-18.5V. We would like to get a fourth panel to get a little more charge to our system.

Can we do a series/parallel combination with this controller?

Our batteries are 12V. But, can we send 24V "nominal" to the charge controller, or is the Voc and Vmp additive when the panel are in series, thus putting us over the 28V Voc and 16.5-18.5 V Vmp limit?

Answer (score 1):

If they are currently set up in parallel and it is working just fine why do you object to putting the 4th one in parallel as well?  looking at the datasheet for the 2512i it looks like you would be fine with 4x75W panels in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

We were thinking of trying to reduce our line loss from the panels to the charge controller/batteries.  About 25 feet.  We are using 8AWG wire, but thought it would be better if we could run 24V to the controller.  Or, we were also thinking of getting one 150W panel that is 24V.  Then put two of the 75W panels in series and parallel it with the 150W.  But, again the Voc and Vmp are over the "allowable" V for the controller.  Sorry if I am not supposed to answer the question to my question here!

John